# Print integer without fraction part

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, pgfmath

In a Tikz Figure, I'm doing some computation and want to print results as label of nodes.
The problem is that I only need the integer part of the number to print.

I tried with round() function. It round the values correctly but they are printed with `.0`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \foreach \i in {1,2,3,4,5,6} {
      \pgfmathparse{round(\i*100/3) }
       \let\theIntINeed\pgfmathresult
       \draw (\i,0) node {\theIntINeed};
   }
 \end{tikzpicture}
 % Results: 33.0 67.0 100.0 133.0 167.0 200.0
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`\pgfmathparse` always saves its result with a decimal part. You can either use `\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}` in the node text to output the number, which will remove the `.0` for integers, or do the calculation using `\pgfmathtruncatemacro\mymacro{round(\i*100/3)}`, which will save the result of the calculation without the decimal part, and then use `\mymacro` in the node text.

Answer (score 56):

You could also use the `int` function, which returns the integer part of the value, i.e.

```
\pgfmathparse{int(round(\i*100/3))}
```

Comment: This should be the actual answer.

Answer (score 9):

Simply use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro\theIntINeed` instead of `\pgfmathresult`.